# How can I remove the maximum API level from an Ionic app?

Tags: android, google-play, ionic-framework

I'm trying to publish an Ionic-based mobile app in the Google Play Store.

I published a previous version of the app, which supported API levels 17+, in the Google Play Developer Console. In the new version I'm trying to publish now, I made the following settings in the config.xml file:

```
...
<platform name="android">
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17"/>
  <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="22"/>
...
```

After creating, signing and zipaligning the app and uploading it to the Developer Console, I got an error messge in the Console saying this configuration cannot be published because a downgrade to the old app version would not be possible in case a device with API level 17-22 is updated to API level 23+.

This kind of makes sense to me, also I actually don't want to force my users to downgrade my already installed app to a previous version if they upgrade their API level. Therefore I deleted the `android-maxSdkVersion` line from the config.xml file. However, after uploading the app again, the Developer Console still tells me that the app's API level is 17-22 and keeps showing the error. As an experiment I tried using:

```
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="23"/>
```

This change actually got reflected in the Developer Console. The uploaded apk's API level is now shown as 17-23, but I also get the matching error message, which now says that a downgrade of my app would not be possible if a user's device would be upgraded to API level 24+.

So changes in the value of the `android-maxSdkVersion` get reflected in the apk, but removing the line from the config.xml file has no effect. How can I change my app's API level back to "17+"?

Comment: If nothing else, you could always set the value to something really high, like `99999`, figuring that either 1) you would never hit it, or 2) some other engineer can deal with the problem when you *do* hit it. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare: I'd be OK with this solution, but the issue is that the Google Play Developer Console still wouldn't let me publish it, because users would have to perform a forbidden downgrade of my app if their API level gets upgraded to 100000+. ;-)